# C: why "sscanf" doesn't cut trailing characters?

Tags: c, scanf

The following C code,

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
  char *source="{\"address\":\"10.10.2.130\"}";
  char ip[32];
  sscanf(source, "{\"address\":\"%s\"}", ip);
  printf("%s\n%s\n", source, ip);
  return 0;
}
```

I expect to extract 10.10.2.130 in ip, but the output shows 10.10.2.130"}, why?

Thanks.

Comment: Because the `%s` format means to read until it reaches whitespace or the end of the string.

Comment: If you want to do pattern matching, use a regular expression library.

Comment: I think you misunderstand how `sscanf` works entirely. It doesn't try to match the input to a template you specify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each part of the format string is executed without looking forward to see what's to come. So the `%s` matches the rest of the string. The subsequent characters in the format string just fail to match because you're trying to match characters that have already been read.

You may want something like `%[^\"]s`, which additionally stops reading if a quote is encountered.

Answer (score 1):

`%s` stops scanning when it reaches whitespace or the end of the source string. Since the string you want to extract is terminated by a `"` character, you can use `%[^"]` to stop scanning on the first `"` character that is encountered, eg:

```
sscanf(source, "{\"address\":\"%[^\"]\"}", ip);
```

Answer (score 1):

The specification of `%s` is:

> Match a sequence of non-white-space characters.

Since the trailing `"}` is not whitespace, it's included in the match.

Instead, you can use the `%[0-9.]` format to match just numbers and dot.

```
sscanf(source, "{\"address\":\"%[0-9.]\"}", ip);
```